# Duration.parse example

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using jodatime's [Duration](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class to add a duration like 02:10 to a DateTime like 2014-08-02T11:34 using withDurationAdded(duration, 1).

I created duration using Duration.parse("02:10").  I get an IllegalFormatException for the "02:10".  I don't see a formatSpecifier argument; how do I properly create this duration?  The jodatime quickstart guide didnt provide an example of parse: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.String)) specifies the required format for `Duration.parse`:

> Parses a Duration from the specified string.
>
> This parses the format `PTa.bS`, as per `AbstractDuration.toString()`.

You'll need to build a custom formatter - here's some sample code:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendHours()
            .appendLiteral(":")
            .appendMinutes()
            .toFormatter();
        Duration duration = formatter.parsePeriod("02:10").toStandardDuration();
        System.out.println(duration);
    }
}
```